# Call function with parameter and place it in a fetch request

Tags: javascript, parameters, fetch, function-call

```
input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    getData();
  }
});

function getData() {
  let getSearchInput = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
  fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${getSearchInput}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
     
      }
```

How can I call the function getData with a parameter which is going to replace the "getSearchInput" variable dynamically? I want to be able to call the getData function with different url endings at different points in my code. Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the value as a param and check the value is present or not with condition

```
function getData(val) { // param
  let getSearchInput = val ? val : document.getElementById("search-input").value;
  fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${getSearchInput}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
     .....
```